# Output of Chrome Version(s) to CSV in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to Query a bunch of servers for The following.
A) Does it have Chrome Installed
B) What version is installed.

I found I could query the c:\program files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application Dir and it will tell me the related folders.  Some have Just one,  most have 2 or more

When I output that to the screen,  It looks pretty good.  When I attempt to export to CSV,  it does not (for any that have it installed.

What am I missing?

```
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]@()
foreach($server in Get-Content d:\chkchromever\servers.txt) { 
If(Test-Path \\$server\c$\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application) {
# Chrome Path Exists-
$VersionNumber=(Get-ChildItem -Path \\$server\c$\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application|where {$_.name -match "\d\d.*"}).Name 
Write-Host $server','$VersionNumber
$obj= [pscustomobject]@{
Server=$server
Version=$VersionNumber
}
$List.Add($obj);
$list | Export-Csv -Path "D:\chkchromever\output.csv "
}
else {
Write-Host $server "does not have Chrome"
$obj= [pscustomobject]@{
Server=$server
Version= "Not Installed"
}
$List.Add($obj);
$list | Export-Csv -Path "D:\chkchromever\output.csv"
}
}
```

Powershell Output:
PS C:\Windows\system32> D:\chkchromever\chkversion2.ps1
Server1,76.0.3809.132 86.0.4240.198
Server2,106.0.5249.103 106.0.5249.119
Server3 does not have Chrome
Server4 does not have Chrome

CSV File
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Server Version
Server1 System.Object[]
server2 System.Object[]
server3 Not Installed

Comment: `get-package 'google chrome'`

Answer (score 0):

A csv is not designed to store arrays. So you have to use another format e.g. json or you have to flattern the structure or to join the the array to string.

You could do

```
$obj= [pscustomobject]@{
   Server=$server
   Version=($VersionNumber -join "|")
}
```